# How can I programmatically find out if a local file is under TFS version control while offline

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a small in-house visual studio extension (VS 2013) and for one feature, I need to figure out if a file on disk is under TFS version control or not.

(By *"under TFS version control"* i mean that the file in question is tracked by TFS, so that it can be checked out, edited, checked in, etc.)

The following code is what I have today, and it works fine as long as you are connected to TFS. It uses an instance of a [Workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.workspace.aspx)

```
// m_workspace is of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace
var items = m_workspace.GetItems(
              new[] {new ItemSpec(filename, RecursionType.None)}, 
              DeletedState.Any, 
              ItemType.Any,
              false, 
              GetItemsOptions.LocalOnly | GetItemsOptions.Unsorted);
return items.First().Items.Any();
```

Now, the problem is that when you are not inside the office firewall (or connected through VPN), the TFS server is not reachable. In fact, the hostname won't even resolve.

**So my question is:** is there any other way for me to find out if a file is under version control? Preferably using the public API, but I'm fine with an ugly hack if that's what it takes...

Comment: Is this a local workspace or a server workspace?  There is no way to do this with a server workspace (as there is simply not enough data locally to answer this question).  However, this should be possible with a local workspace.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a server workspace. I understand that while offline, it's impossible to know the current state on the server, but I would be ok to just know the state as of whenever the last 'Get latest' was performed.

Comment: This is a good question, but regrettably, the only state that's kept on the client is the workspace mappings.  This *may* help you:  these will let you determine whether a file is inside a mapped folder or not.  You may be able to deduce then that a read-only file inside a mapped folder is in TFS.  Writable files are trickier: they may be checked out, they may be pending adds or they may just be files that are not meant to be added to source control at all. (Though we would recommend cloaking those files explicitly.)  I can assist w/ getting workfold info if it would help given those caveats.

Comment: @EdwardThomson if you describe how to do that in an answer, I'd accept it if nobody has a better solution. I'm fine with a hack that at least solves part of it :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @IsakSavo? I have local workspace and I need to know if a file is already under source control or not.

Comment: Unfortunately not @SaeedNeamati :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
   string underTfs = Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation.Current.IsMapped(path);
```

Comment: This method returns always true even if the given file isn't mapped.

Comment: Yeah, I tested, it always returns true.